# Match Stable Packages to Previous Versions of R?

Tags: r, package, version, cran

I have a secure internal network that installs pre-approved R packages from an internal folder.

The entity I work for is updating to a new version of R (3.6.2) but some will need to remain on 3.5.2 for several months. I am aware that many packages are R version specific. I wish to put together a list of which versions of CRAN packages work with each in order to ensure this internal folder is updated accordingly.

What is the best resource to do this with?

The only way I can see so far is to initialise a virtual env with each version and work through each package unless there is a more efficient way that others in the same boat have found?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `miniCRAN::pkgDep`. From `help("pkgDep")`:

> Performs recursive retrieve for Depends, Imports and LinkLibrary. Performs non-recursive retrieve for Suggests.

```
library(miniCRAN)
packages <- pkgDep("data.table")
packages
 [1] "data.table"  "bit"         "R.oo"        "R.methodsS3" "evaluate"    "highr"       "markdown"    "stringr"     "yaml"        "xfun"       
[11] "mime"        "glue"        "magrittr"    "stringi"     "zoo"         "lattice"     "bit64"       "RcppCCTZ"    "Rcpp"        "curl"       
[21] "R.utils"     "knitr"       "xts"         "nanotime"
```

Then you can use the information from `base::available.packages`:

```
avail.pack <- available.packages()
unique(avail.pack[rownames(avail.pack) %in% packages,"Depends"])
 [1] "R (>= 2.9.2)"                                         "R (>= 3.0.1), bit (>= 1.1-12), utils, methods, stats"
 [3] "R (>= 3.0.0)"                                         "R (>= 3.1.0)"                                        
 [5] "R (>= 3.0.2)"                                         "R (>= 3.1)"                                          
 [7] "R (>= 3.2.3)"                                         NA                                                    
 [9] "R (>= 2.11.1)"                                        "R (>= 2.13.0)"                                       
[11] "R (>= 2.13.0), R.methodsS3 (>= 1.7.1)"                "R (>= 2.14.0), R.oo (>= 1.23.0)"                     
[13] "R (>= 2.14)"                                          "zoo (>= 1.7-12)"                                     
[15] "R (>= 3.1.0), stats"
```